# how to fix "500 internal server error in retrofit and web services" in asp.net web method

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, post, retrofit

I am trying to insert the record using asp.net web-services from the android platform using retrofit. I have already tried many solutions but not able to get success.

Basically in my asp.net web service code is:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void insertEducationAPI(int user_id, string degree_name, string institute_name, string board_university_name, int year_of_passing, float percentage_cgpa, string specialization)
{

    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        //These headers are handling the "pre-flight" OPTIONS call sent by the browser
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }

    Education edu = new Education();
    string result = educationModel.addEducation(user_id, degree_name, institute_name, board_university_name, year_of_passing, percentage_cgpa, specialization);
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    Context.Response.Clear();
    Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

    if (result.Equals("complete"))
    {
        edu.err = false;
        edu.err_message = "Inserted success";
    }
    else
    {
        edu.err = true;
        edu.err_message = "Fail";
    }
    Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(edu));
}
```

### And at android side

### API interface:

```
@Headers({
        "Accept: application/json",
        "Content-Type: application/json"
})
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/EducationApi.asmx/insertEducationAPI")
public void insertEducationDetail(@Field("user_id") int user_id, @Field("degree_name") String degree_name, @Field("institute_name") String institute_name, @Field("board_university_name") String board_university_name, @Field("year_of_passing") int year_of_passing, @Field("percentage_cgpa") float percentage_cgpa, @Field("specialization") String specialization, Callback<Education> callback);
}
```

---

### Method calling;

```
retro.getService().insertEducationDetail(1, "MCA", "SRIMCA", "UTU", 2015, 85, ".NET", new Callback<Education>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Education education, Response response) {
            Toast.makeText(Dashboard.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Toast.makeText(Dashboard.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

---

Error:

```
I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x87d71180) (w:720 h:1440 s:736 f:0x1 u:b00)
D/Retrofit: <--- HTTP 500 http://192.168.43.25:81/EducationApi.asmx/insertEducationAPI (77ms)
    : HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
    Cache-Control: private
D/Retrofit: Content-Length: 91
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    Date: Sat, 10 Aug 2019 20:36:09 GMT
D/Retrofit: jsonerror: true
D/Retrofit: Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
    X-Android-Received-Millis: 1565469369999
    X-Android-Response-Source: NETWORK 500
    X-Android-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
    X-Android-Sent-Millis: 1565469369982
    X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
D/Retrofit: {"Message":"There was an error processing the request.","StackTrace":"","ExceptionType":""}
    <--- END HTTP (91-byte body)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

On the Android side your API interface looks incorrect:

```java
@POST("/EducationApi.asmx/addEducationAPI")
public void addEducation(@Body List<Education> education, Callback<Education> callback);
```

It's not a `List<Education>` on the server side, just a single `Education` object, so the definition should probably be:

```java
@POST("/EducationApi.asmx/addEducationAPI")
public void addEducation(@Body Education education, Callback<Education> callback);
```

== edit ==

Also, you have only decorated your API method with `[WebMethod]` so it only accepts SOAP+XML input. To be callable with JSON you need to add the `[ScriptMethod]` decoration, e.g.:

```cs
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public void addEducationAPI(Education education)
{
    //...
}
```

Due to security requirements of the `[ScriptMethod]` attribute (see [JSON Hijacking and How ASP.NET AJAX 1.0 Avoids these Attacks](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/json-hijacking-and-how-asp-net-ajax-1-0-mitigates-these-attacks)) you need to ensure that your Retrofit requests include a `Content-Type: application/json` header. e.g.:

```java
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("/EducationApi.asmx/addEducationAPI")
public void addEducation(@Body Education education, Callback<Education> callback);
```

You should also add an `Accept: application/json` header if Retrofit isn't already doing that for you. e.g.:

```java
@Headers({
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Content-Type: application/json"
})
@POST("/EducationApi.asmx/addEducationAPI")
public void addEducation(@Body Education education, Callback<Education> callback);
```

Including both of these headers in your requests will allow you to delete your JavaScriptSerializer code, and just return an instance of `Education`. When using `[ScriptMethod]` the ASP.NET web service framework will automatically return SOAP+XML for SOAP+XML requests and return JSON for JSON requests.

So a full working example, which also includes the `[ScriptService]` attribute on the `EducationApi` class, looks like:

```cs
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ScriptService]
public class EducationApi : WebService
{
    EducationModel educationModel = new EducationModel();

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod]
    public Education addEducationAPI(Education education)
    {
        Education edu = new Education();
        string result = educationModel.addEducation(
            education.user_id,
            education.degree_name,
            education.institute_name,
            education.board_university_name,
            education.year_of_passing,
            education.percentage_cgpa,
            education.specialization);
        if (result.Equals("complete"))
        {
            edu.err = false;
            edu.err_message = "Inserted success";
        }
        else
        {
            edu.err = true;
            edu.err_message = "Fail";
        }
        return edu;
    }
}
```

And posting data to it with the `curl` utility:

```sh
curl --data '{"education":{"__type":"Education","user_id":1,"degree_name":"MCA","institute_name":"SRIMCA","board_university_name":"UTU","year_of_passing":2015,"specialization":"None","percentage_cgpa":85}}' --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" --trace-ascii - http://127.0.0.1:8080/EducationApi.asmx/addEducationAPI
```

Returns the JSON result:

```
{"d":{"user_id":0,"degree_name":null,"institute_name":null,"board_university_name":null,"year_of_passing":0,"specialization":null,"percentage_cgpa":0,"err":false,"err_message":"Inserted success"}}
```

Comment: I have already tried this but not work. The same error occurs "500 internal servers". Please suggest me another solution.

Comment: I have also tried your suggested code then also it generates the error "500 internal servers".

Comment: @AkshayJain: a 500 error means that there was a problem, and the problem details will be in server logs. Look at your server logs to see what the issue is.

Comment: @halfer: This error occurs:  {"Message":"There was an error processing the request.","StackTrace":"","ExceptionType":""}---------but i am not able to understand this problem.

Comment: @AkshayJain: that is not a bad start. However it seems to be missing some key details, which makes me wonder if you could increase the log level in your server. It may be set to "info" or something like that, and it would need to be set to "debug". Can you research that to see if that is possible in your system?

Comment: Hello @halfer now I have updated my problem. Please help me to solve this problem.              https://stackoverflow.com/q/57439576/10325004

Comment: @AkshayJain: you appear not to have added anything more than the error you mentioned in my comment. I have suggested a next step, which is to do some research on how to improve the quality of the logging messages. Are you able to do that next?